# Monodroid build error on startup project

Tags: xamarin.android

I just downloaded and installed Mono for Mac along with Mono for Android. Selecting file `->` new solution `->` new MonoDroid Application, and trying to build that, I just get an error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Novell/Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets:
Error: Invalid or unrecognized TargetFrameworkVersion 'v1.0' (AppName)
```

Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the correct MonoDevelop? You need to be using the one here:

http://monodevelop.com/Download/Mono_For_Android#Mac

You should also make sure that you're using Mono 2.10 (as the error you're mentioning looks like an xbuild error).

Comment: I was sure I had Mono 2.10, but obviously not.